# Laplacian of two scalar fields

Tags: vector-analysis, solution-verification, laplacian, scalar-fields

I am trying to find  $$\nabla^2 (gh)$$
so far I have $$\nabla^2 (gh) = \nabla\cdot(\nabla(gh)) = \nabla\cdot(g\nabla h+h\nabla g) = \nabla\cdot(g\nabla h)+\nabla\cdot(h\nabla g)$$

I am not sure the last step is correct.

I am trying to show that $$\nabla^2 (gh) = g(\nabla^2 h) + 2(\nabla g)\cdot(\nabla h) + h(\nabla^2 g)$$

In particular, I am not sure how to treat $$\nabla\cdot(g\nabla h)$$ is there a rule that I am missing?
thanks

Comment: try writing what you have out in coordinates, I think you can see where to go

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the correct solution:$$\nabla^2(gh)$$

$$= \nabla\cdot\nabla(gh)$$
$$=\nabla\cdot(g\nabla h+h\nabla g)$$
$$=\nabla\cdot (g\nabla h)+\nabla\cdot(h\nabla g)$$
$$=(\nabla g)\cdot\nabla h +g(\nabla\cdot\nabla h)+(\nabla h)\cdot\nabla g + h(\nabla\cdot\nabla g)$$
$$=g\nabla^2h +2(\nabla g)\cdot(\nabla h)+h\nabla^2g$$

Shown as required